# Issue with lodash's isEmpty when dealing with files

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the issue with lodash's isEmpty method when we dealing with files from event.target.files.
Here's a sample 
https://jsfiddle.net/qr896akv/

```
document
  .getElementById('inputTypeFile')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    console.log('files', files);
    console.log('files.length', files.length);
    console.log('typeof files', typeof files);
    console.log('files instanceof FileList', files instanceof FileList);
    console.log('_.isEmpty(files)', _.isEmpty(files));
    console.log('_.isEmpty(files[0])',_.isEmpty(files[0])); //  return 'true' :-(
  });
```

When we try `_.isEmpty(files[0])`, it's returning `true` even though the data is there. Any idea if this is the expected result from lodash perspective or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea if this is the expected result from lodash perspective or not

Yes, this is expected behaviour, from the lodash docs on [`_.isEmpty()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty):

> Objects are considered empty if they have no own enumerable string
>   keyed properties
>
> - [Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty)

You can see that `files[0]` doesn't have any own enumerable property names by using `Object.keys(files[0])`, which returns:

> an array of a given object's own enumerable property names
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

As doing `Object.keys(files[0])` gives an empty array, lodash sees your object as being empty, and hence it returns `true`.